# Convert shape to polygons

Tags: c#, opengl, polygon, shapes

Is there any simple (or not) algorithm that is capable of creating polygons from closed path?

Assume w have following path:

```
0,0; 2,0, 2,1; 1,1;
1,2; 2,2; 2,3; 0,3;
```

I need to be able to create polygon indexes for OpenGL vertex buffer. Language I'm using is C#.

Someone suggested me Convex Hull, but it's not the thing I'm looking for, cause I have a shape already. I know that this could be a trivial issue, but seriously, I can't find any description or something to point mi in the right direction.

Edit:

Answer 1 suggest to select a point and connect it to other not connected points, this works fine for presented in answer shape but it will not work for shape i posted, shape above looks like this:

[image: Shape]

Comment: You want to triangulate this polygon? Or do you intend to use `GL_POLYGON`?

Comment: I use `GL_TRIANGLES` in function `glDrawElements` to render vertex buffer, so I need vertices (above), indices (this I need to establish having shape), and normals (currently not needed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting to triangles is either easy or hard, depending on what your requirements are and how well you want to do it.

If your polygon is convex, the easiest way is to use `GL_TRIANGLES` with the indicies

```
0, 1, 2,   0, 2, 3,  0, 3, 4, ...
```

It will look like this:

[image: triangulation by fanning]

The situation for concave is more work. An algorithm that also works for concave polygons (not ones with holes!) is the Ear-clipping method, described on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) (there is more on that page.)

Things get really interesting when you want a "good" triangulation: avoid skinny or small triangles, reduce number of triangles etc., and then you can trade off quality for speed. I won't go into any advanced algorithms here; searching for polygon triangulation on Google will get you lots of info.

As for normals, if your polygon is planar (it most likely "should" be) then take two non co-incident edges and cross product them (there are two normals and you probably only want one: you need to choose the order in which you cross product (clockwise or anticlockwise) based on the [right hand rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation).

Comment: I came up with this approach, but it won't work on every, at least not with shapes that my project require. I updated my question to make things clear.

Comment: Yes, as I said the fan-out approach won't work for concave polygons. (It's also pretty bad in general) I mentioned a solution that would (ear-clipping, there is a link - it also mentions a few other methods) and if you want more algorithms you should search google for "polygon triangulation", as there are many of them with different tradeoffs.

Comment: Man, you are awesome. Searching for ear clipping (I was missing the name :P) I came across [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8238/Polygon-Triangulation-in-C)